# How to make Uploadify queue scrollable

Tags: jquery, html, css, uploadify

Just a quick question I can't find the answer to. How can I make the uploadify queue div scrollable. I noticed that the queued files are saved to a class named `uploadify-queue`. I tried modifying the `uploadify.css` by adding `width`,`height` and `overflow` but doesn't work. I think the queue files are floating.

My HTML structure:

```
<div id="Uploader">
  <div id="UploaderSpot">
    <div id="UploaderField">
      // this content is replaced by Uploadify
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that div `UploaderSpot` has a fixed with and height and if I select to upload 100 files, those files get queue outside `UploaderField`...

Example:
[image]

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Uploadify creates a child container DIV inside. Try styling this:

```
<style type="text/css">
.uploadifyQueue {
     height: 200px;
     overflow: scroll;
}
</style>
```

Comment: there is also `.uploadifyQueueItem` for each item, which when processed will have a class of `.completed`. Make sure this CSS is loaded after or is edited within uploadify.css (comes with the package)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is to use the queueID option and create your own queue container.

```
<input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" />
<div id="my_queue"></div>
```

Then in your Uploadify Call:

```
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
    ...
    queueID : 'my_queue'
});
```

And style it with:

```
#my_queue {
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

With `overflow: auto;` the scrollbars will only appear when it gets passed the bounds of the queue.